# How to give name to each node in celery

Tags: python, celery, supervisord

We are using celery with our flask application. There are many queues for our various tasks and we use supervisord to run queues. We use cloudamqp 
broker.

Example supervisor configuration is like below:

```
[program:my-queue]
command=/home/ubuntu/opt/proect/venv/bin/celery -A async_runner worker -Q my_queue --loglevel=INFO --without-gossip --without-mingle --autoscale=1,1  -c 1
environment=PYTHONPATH=/home/ubuntu/opt/project/,PRODUCTION_ENVIRONMENT=true
directory=/home/ubuntu/opt/project/app

process_name = %(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
user=ubuntu
numprocs=2
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
stopwaitsecs = 600
priority=998
```

We get following error and queues just stop.

```
[2017-04-06 12:43:06,759: WARNING/MainProcess] /home/ubuntu/opt/project/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/pidbox.py:75: UserWarning: A node named celery@ip-xxx-yy-yy-yy is already using this process mailbox!

Maybe you forgot to shutdown the other node or did not do so properly?
Or if you meant to start multiple nodes on the same host please make sure
you give each node a unique node name!

  warnings.warn(W_PIDBOX_IN_USE.format(node=self))
```

Question: How to give names to each node?

When I run `celery -A async_runner status` it gives 5 nodes online message.

```
celery@ip-ip_value_here-: OK
celery@ip-ip_value_here-: OK
celery@ip-ip_value_here-: OK
celery@ip-ip_value_here-: OK
celery@ip-ip_value_here-: OK

5 nodes online.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is how we run one celery worker for each queue in our company. The entry point contains this:

```
echo QUEUES: ${QUEUES}  # comma separated list of queue names
export NUM_QUEUES=$(python -c "print len('$QUEUES'.split(','))")
echo NUM_QUEUES: ${NUM_QUEUES}

supervisord &
```

The supervisor config file has this:

```
[program:worker]
command=/path/to/celery_worker.sh %(process_num)s
# supervisor uses the special ENV_ prefix to get the environment variable set above
numprocs=%(ENV_NUM_QUEUES)s
```

And finally `celery_worker.sh` contains something like:

```
QUEUE=$(python -c "print '$QUEUES'.split(',')[$1]")  # $1 = process_num above
celery worker -n "worker.${QUEUE}" -Q ${QUEUE}  # -n sets the name of the worker
```

Comment: Not sure I understand and if this answers my question.

Comment: @soupboy sorry, should have clarified that `-n` sets the name of the worker, which it sounds like you need.

Comment: @soupboy actually I see now you're running multiple workers for the same queue, so you'll want to include that `process_num` in the worker name as well.

Answer (score 4):

Use option `-n SOMENODENAME@%%h` . The `@%%h` will make sure that each worker has a unique nodename

Comment: I am guessing this only works if each worker is on a different host?